# How to programmatical import module to local scope of nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

The code environment is browser. bundle tool is webpack. I have a router.js file like:

```
import foo from './views/foo.vue'
import bar from './views/bar.vue'
import zoo from './views/zoo.vue'

//use foo, bar, zoo variables
```

I've many '.vue' files to import like this under `views` folder. Is there a programmatical way to auto import all `[name].vue` as local variable `[name]`? So when I add or remove a vue file in `views`, I don't need to manually edit `router.js` file. this one seems a little dirty.

```
for (let name of ['foo', 'bar', 'zoo']) {
    global[name] = require(`./views/${name}.vue`)
}
```

Comment: Not with `import` - because `import` is processed at compile time, not run time, there is no code you can write to affect it. But since `require` is just a regular function you can write code to control it like you posted. It is not dirty at all. Since `require` is a regular function it is perfectly OK to treat it as a regular function and call it inside a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that's it. You have a choice between dynamic import and automation, or explicit coding and type-checking / linting.

Unfortunately, it's one or the other. The only other way to do it is meta-programming, where you write code to write your code.

So you generate the import statements in a loop like that, and write the string into the source file, and use delimiting comment blocks in the source file to identify and update it.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me with webpack and vue.
I actually use it for vuex and namespaces. Hope it helps you as well.

```
// imports all .vue files from the views folder (first parameter is the path to your views)
const requireModule = require.context('./views', false, /\.vue$/);

// create empty modules object
const modules = {};

// travers through your imports
requireModule.keys().forEach(item => {

  // replace extension with nothing
  const moduleName = item.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, '');
  
  // add item to modules object
  modules[moduleName] = requireModule(item).default;
});

//export modules object
export default modules;
```

Comment: thanks. though not a direct answer, I apply your method.